# Eclipselink read complex object model in an ordered way

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipselink

I need to read a complex model in an ordered way with eclipselink. The order is mandantory because it is a huge database and I want to have an output of a small portion of the database in a jface tableview. Trying to reorder it in the loading/quering thread takes too long and ordering it in the LabelProvider blocks the UI thread too much time, so I thought if Eclipselink could be used that way, that the database will order it, it might give me the performance I need. Unfortunately the object model can not be changed :-(

The model is something like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class Thing implements Serializable {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
     private int id;
     private String name;
     @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     @PrivateOwned
     private List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<Property>();
     ...
     // getter and setter following here
}
public class Property implements Serializable { 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    private Item item;

     private String value;
     ...
     // getter and setter following here
}
public class Item implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;
    private String name;
     ....
     // getter and setter following here    
}
// Code end
```

In the table view the y-axis is more or less created with the query

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Thing m ORDER BY m.name ASC");
```

using the "name" attribute from the Thing objects as label.

In the table view the x-axis is more or less created with the query

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Item m ORDER BY m.name ASC");
```

using the "name" attribute from the Item objects as label.

Each cell has the value

```
Things.getProperties().get[x].getValue()
```

Unfortunately the list "properties" is not ordered, so the combination of cell value and x-axis column number (x) is not necessarily correct. Therefore I need to order the list "properties" in the same way as I ordered the labeling of the x-axis.

And exactly this is the thing I dont know how it is done. So querying for the Thing objects should return the list "properties" "ORDER BY name ASC" *but* of the "Item"s objects. My ideas are something like having a query with two JOINs. Joing Things with Property and with Item but somehow I was unable to get it to work yet.

Thank you for your help and your ideas to solve this riddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the answer to this other question could help you:
[Defining the order of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105099/defining-the-order-of-a-list)

I think you may have to use another query to get the list of properties order by item.name for each thing.

Something like:

```
SELECT p FROM Property p WHERE p.thing = ?1 ORDER BY p.item.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `@OrderBy` JPA annotation. Something like

```
@OrderBy('name ASC')
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<Property>();
```

Comment: Thanks!!
Unluckily I get this error:
"Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7217] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The order by value [name], specified on the element [properties] from entity [class Thing], is invalid. No property or field with that name exists on the target entity [class Property]."
It seems eclipselink doesnt know about the name field in Item.name yet.

Comment: Yet I added the @OrderBy to the Item.name and this doesnt help. Eclipselink still reads the list in an unordered manner. :-(

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. EclipseLink shoulkd support @OrderBy, but it does not help in your case.

Comment: No, it doesnt.
I figured out a SQL query which works on the database, but eclipselink doesnt construct my objects with it. Any hints?
SELECT * FROM Thing AS a 
JOIN Thing_Property AS b ON a.id=b.Thing_ID 
JOIN Property AS c  ON b.properties_ID = c.id
JOIN Item AS d ON c.item_ID = d.id
ORDER BY a.name, d.name

Comment: This must be possible on JPQL as well, something like:

SELECT * FROM Thing a JOIN a.property c JOIN c.item d JOIN ORDER BY a.name, d.name