# Hibernate @OrderBy for nested properties

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I need to use @OrderBy (JPA, Hibernate as provider) to sort collection for nested property:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "paramSpec", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderBy("release.ordinal")
private List<PkdbParameter> pkdbParams;
```

In PkdbParameter.java:

```
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "release_id")
private Release release;
...
```

In Release.java:

```
...
private int ordinal;
...
```

(all of these fields have simple getters and setters provided)

Unfortunately I'm getting error:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: property from @OrderBy clause not found: some.package.PkdbParameter.release.ordinal`

What's wrong with this code? If it's impossible to use nested properties notation is there any other way to order for `ordinal` property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@OrderBy` works only with direct properties or embedded attributes. From [Java EE 6 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html)

> The dot (".") notation is used to refer to an attribute within an embedded attribute

So if the `Release` is an embedded attribute, this could work. Otherwise you could use named query as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105099/defining-the-order-of-a-list/1105370#1105370)

Answer (score 11):

You can use the Hibernate `@SortComparator` annotation:

Like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "paramSpec", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@SortComparator(ReleaseComparator.class)
private List<PkdbParameter> pkdbParams;
```

Where CameraNameComparator is:

```
public class ReleaseComparator implements Comparator<PkdbParameter> {
    @Override
    public int compare(PkdbParameter o1, PkdbParameter o2) {
        return o1.getRelease().getOrdinal().compareTo( o2.getRelease().getOrdinal() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the order statements and place it on non collection properties:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "paramSpec", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderBy("release")
private List<PkdbParameter> pkdbParams;
```

and

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "release_id")
@OrderBy("ordinal")
private Release release;
```

As a side effect, you have fixed sort order for PkdbParameter.

Comment: I tried this one but it seems ordering a ManyToOne is just ignored.

Comment: This will simply ``ORDER BY pkdbParams1_.release`` and ignore the ``ordinal`` property altogether, which is most certainly not what the original poster wants.

Comment: Is it possibly a different behavior on Hibernate versions?

Comment: Set ``hibernate.show_sql = true`` in your ``persistence.xml`` file and see for yourself, what SQL code is created by Hibernate.

Comment: Thank you for verifying this thesis.