# From Hibernate 4.2.6 to 4.3.1 issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

> Edit: I was able to boil down the issue to Hibernate but I still need help on it.

I'm having a weird issue with Hibernate since I updated Netbeans from 8.0.0 to 8.0.1 where all of our projects using Hibernate don't work anymore.
Unfortunately our projects are missing proper dependency management until now. So, we are using the respective Hibernate version "shipped" with Netbeans (in NB 8.0.0 it's Hibernate 4.2.6 and in NB 8.0.1 it's Hibernate 4.3.1).

After fiddling with a missing dependency (Jandex 1.1.0 Final) finally one of our products runs again but the other one doesn't and it gives me a very weird exception saying a certain column does not exist (but it worked before).

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
at ch.company.product2.disporesgp.logic.MyRouteLogic.getMyRouteFromToDateWithReservationsAndActive(MyRouteLogic.java:61)
at ch.company.product2.disposition.view.NormalWorkPanel.refreshQueryData(NormalWorkPanel.java:1300)
at ch.company.product2.disposition.view.NormalWorkPanel$1.run(NormalWorkPanel.java:119)
at ch.company.product2.util.CursorTemplate.doCursor(CursorTemplate.java:36)
at ch.company.product2.disposition.view.NormalWorkPanel.<init>(NormalWorkPanel.java:121)
at ch.company.product2.disposition.view.HomeView.<init>(HomeView.java:74)
at ch.company.product2.disposition.view.Login$7.run(Login.java:380)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:449)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:202)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:186)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4120)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:502)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:467)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:212)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:274)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1066)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:985)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:673)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:489)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:170)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:144)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1114)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column visitedstations.hours does not exist
Position: 2141
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
... 39 more
```

(Sorry for the cluttered exception. We're running some queries on user login which makes up for some extra messages in the exception.)

Checking out the [release page for hibernate 4.3.1](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH/fixforversion/15351/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:version-summary-panel) didn't really help

My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MYPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://ip:port/db"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The method mentioned in the exception didn't change and is really just running a NamedQuery.

```
public static List<MyRoute>
        getMyRouteFromToDateWithReservationsAndActive(Date from,
        Date to) {
    EntityManager em = JavaPersistenceUtil.getAndOpenEntityManager();

    return em.createNamedQuery("MyRoute.findFromToDateWithReservationsAndActive")
        .setParameter("from", from, TemporalType.DATE)
        .setParameter("to", to, TemporalType.DATE)
        .getResultList();
}
```

The named query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "MyRoute.findFromToDateWithReservationsAndActive", 
 query = "SELECT DISTINCT r FROM MyRoute r LEFT JOIN FETCH r.section s
 LEFT JOIN FETCH s.from LEFT JOIN FETCH s.to LEFT JOIN FETCH s.reservation res
 LEFT JOIN FETCH res.contact WHERE r.datum >= :from AND r.datum <= :to AND
 (r.reservedTablePlaces > 0 OR r.reservedPlaces > 0) AND r.active = TRUE")
```

The visitedstations entity:

```
@Entity
public class VisitedStation implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
@OneToOne
private Station station;
private int hours;
private int minutes;

...
```

And the table:

```
CREATE TABLE db.visitedstation(
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('db.visitedstation_id_seq'::regclass),
minutes integer NOT NULL,
hours integer NOT NULL,
station_id text,
CONSTRAINT visitedstation_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT visitedstation_station_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (station_id)
    REFERENCES db.station (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Debugging with `hibernate.show_sql` didn't give me any further results besides the fact that the failing query tries to sort the result by `visitedstations.hours` which I don't really understand why.

I'm really out of ideas how to approach this problem further.
It worked fine with Hibernate 4.2.6 and if it's the only option I certainly will go back to the old version (and I will talk my boss into using dependency management anyway) I just would be very thankful for some hints if I'm missing something here. I spent already days trying to understand and fix this and this is my last resort. :-D

I hope I was specific enough... if the post misses some information just let me know.

PS: I did sanitize the code and messages and hope I didn't introduce some typos.

Comment: Have you checked that this column exists in the database?

Comment: Hi. Yes I did. As I wrote, it works perfectly with Hibernate 4.2.6.

Comment: *Works* doesn't automatically mean that column exists.

Comment: That's true. I made some progress in the meantime. I will update the issue description as soon as I read the Hibernate docs about the failing annotation.

Comment: Hey Aleksandr. I found the answer myself but thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the underling problem by looking more closely at the error message:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERROR: column visited1_.hours does not exist
Position: 2141
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener onLoad
INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Looking at the query again (with `hibernate.show_sql`)

> select run0_.id as id1_10_0_ [...] order by visited1_.hours asc, visited1_.minutes asc

This lead me to my "Run" class which holds the following statement

```
@JoinTable(
    name = "run_visitedstation",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "run_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "visitedstation_id")
)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OrderBy("hours ASC, minutes ASC")
private List<VisitedStation> visitedstations;
```

Unfortunately `hours` and `minutes`are not **direct** properties of the `run_visitedstation` jointable but belong to `visitedstation` instead.

As described here: [Hibernate @OrderBy with referenced class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036902/hibernate-orderby-with-referenced-class)

And here: [Hibernate Sort](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-sort)

> “Hibernate currently ignores @OrderBy on @ElementCollection on e.g. List. The order of elements is as returned by the database, undefined.”

This was fixed in Version [4.3.0 Beta 3](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6875) and that's why it worked before (4.2.6), because it was ignored, and now it's not (4.3.1).